# How to parse a file , find out the dict in it , and then create a dict out of it?

Tags: python, django-models

```
# This is an auto-generated Django model module created by ogrinspect.
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class Parking(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    descriptio = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    geom = models.PointField(srid=4326)
    objects = models.GeoManager()

# Auto-generated `LayerMapping` dictionary for Parking model
parking_mapping = {
    'name' : 'Name',
    'descriptio' : 'Descriptio',
    'geom' : 'POINT25D',
}
```

The parking_mapping is the dict in the whole string here . This whole output is stored in a text field . How to parse the text file , extract parking_mapping as a dict named parking_mapping . ?

Comment: Please attempt to reword your question.

Comment: Do you really need to parse the file or merely get parking_mapping?  What's wrong with simply using "from (filename) import parking_mapping"?

Comment: No I don't need to parse the file . I just need the dict

Answer (score 0):

use json module

```
mydict = {'name' : 'foo'}


with open('dump.json', 'w') as f:
    json_str = json.dumps(mydict) // save json_str in database 
    f.write(json_str)

contents = None
with open('dump.json') as f:
    json_str = json.loads(f.read())
    contents = json_str
```

You could walk over contents and look up dictionaries.

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the file why not just name it .py, and it to path, and import parking_mapping?

```
 from <file> import parking_mapping
```